# pygrib ImportError: symbol not found in flat namespace '_grib_context_set_definitions_path'

Tags: python, grib, pygrib, symbol-not-found

I'm encountering an issue with the pygrib library in Python. When I try to import and use pygrib, I receive the following error:

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pygrib/_pygrib.cpython-311-darwin.so, 0x0002): symbol not found in flat namespace '_grib_context_set_definitions_path'
```

**Environment Details:**

Python Version: 3.11
Operating System: MacOS Ventura (13.5.1)
Installation Method: pip

**Steps to Reproduce:**

Installed pygrib using pip install pygrib.
Ran a simple script to import pygrib (see below).

```
import pygrib

grbs = pygrib.open('2m_temperature.grib')

for grb in grbs:
    print(grb)
    exit()
```

**What I've Tried:**

Reinstalled pygrib.
Checked for multiple Python installations and ensured I'm using Python 3.11.
Created a new virtual environment with Python 3.11 and installed pygrib within it.
pip uninstall pygrib (and install again)
Compiled pygrib from source (although I'm not sure I did right).
Searched for similar issues but couldn't find a solution that works for my case.

Does anyone have any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try toCreate/Edit virtual environment "GRIB_DEFINITIONS_PATH" and set its path to "/usr/local/share/eccodes/definitions"

Comment: Thanks @Andrew, I tried that but it didn't work. I decided to go for a different library (cfgrib) and managed to read my files and everything.